# Ruby on Rails textfield to route or specific webpage or to show action rather than list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

The website i am building is in ruby on rails and it is about agriculture equipments. I have build a regular search page with input text field which when used list all items containing keyword

What i am planning to do is to have  a textfield with bootstrap autocomplete feature. The text field will show options depending on input and when a single option is selected, i need it route to the particular items detail page i.e. show page rather than listing the results.

I need help with how to route directly to an items show page using the textfield value.

How can i do that?

Comment: You want search result to be shown by ajax?

Comment: No actually I need the result to be links so when clicked it goes to the particular item's detail page.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Further to the comments, it sounds like you'll be wanting to create some sort of [`livesearch`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) functionality, which basically uses `ajax` to send requests on `keyup` to your backend (`PHP`, `Rails`, etc)

We've done something like this [here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk) (search at the top):

[image]

--

The way to make this work is 3 fold:

> - Specific `ajax` route
> - Javascript to handle `keyup`
> - Controller action to send response

I understand this is not *exactly* what you want, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
    collection do
        get "search(/:query)" #-> domain.com/controler/search/your_query
    end
end
```

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json, :js, :html

    def search
       @response = Model.where value: params[:query]
       respond_with @response
    end
end
```

**JS**

```
#app/assets/javascripts/jquery.livesearch.js
// Author: Ryan Heath
// http://rpheath.com

(function($) {
  $.searchbox = {}

  $.extend(true, $.searchbox, {
    settings: {
        url: 'search',
        param: 'search',
        dom_id: '#livesearch',
        minChars: 2,
        loading_css: '#livesearch_loading',
        del_id: '#livesearch_del'
    },

    loading: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.loading_css).show()
    },

    idle: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.loading_css).hide()
    },

    start: function() {
      $.searchbox.loading()
      $(document).trigger('before.searchbox')
    },

    stop: function() {
      $.searchbox.idle()
      $(document).trigger('after.searchbox')
    },

    kill: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeOut(50)
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeOut(100)
    },

    reset: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeOut(50)
        $('#SearchSearch').val('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeOut(100)
    },

    process: function(terms) {

        if(/\S/.test(terms)) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url:  $.searchbox.settings.url,
                    data: {search: terms.trim()},
                    complete: function(data) {  
                        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeIn(50)
                        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html(data.responseText)

                        if (!$($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).is(':empty')) {
                            $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeIn(100)
                        }

                        $.searchbox.stop();
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }else{
            $.searchbox.kill();
        }
    }
  });



    $.fn.searchbox = function(config) {
        var settings = $.extend(true, $.searchbox.settings, config || {})

        $(document).trigger('init.searchbox')
        $.searchbox.idle()

        return this.each(function() {
            var $input = $(this)

            $input
            .keyup(function() { 
                if ($input.val() != this.previousValue) {

                    if(/\S/.test($input.val().trim()) &&  $input.val().trim().length > $.searchbox.settings.minChars){ 
                        $.searchbox.start()
                        $.searchbox.process($input.val())
                    }else{
                        $.searchbox.kill()
                    }

                    this.previousValue = $input.val()

                }
            })
        })
    }
})(jQuery);


#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//Livesearch
$(document).ready( function() {
    var base_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

    $('#SearchSearch').searchbox({
        url: base_url + '/search/',
        param: 'search',
        dom_id: '#livesearch',
        loading_css: '#livesearch_loading'
    })      
});
```